# Silverlight WCF Service Error

Tags: silverlight, wcf

What would prevent one machine from consuming a Silverlight Enabled WCF service some of the time, whilst another on the same network domain, behind the same proxy / firewall / etc.. can fine? Service and app are on the same domain.

I'm writing to the event log when the service comes in, and I can't even see the call come through.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

**Update:** After using fiddler, it seems to work if we have fiddler running, but not if we don't. I'm more confused than ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lesson is never believe what your told. The proxy on the non-working machine was indeed different. :o\

Fiddler drops itself into the [proxy chain](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp) and that's what caused it to work whilst fiddler was running.

Case sovled.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) and see what is going on. No other good way to figure this out (sometimes even fiddler can't help).

Comment: Where would you put fiddler? On the machine running the silverlight app I guess...

Good suggestion tho, I'll give it a shot today - thanks! :o)